# concat string and numbers without removing zeros

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and currently using mySQL CONCAT to create an id from `Letters` ie, ABC with `Number` ie, 00005.
The CONCAT removes the leading zeros from the number. How do I maintain the original number with leading zeros so the output is

ABC00005

not

ABC5

```
CONCAT(`Letters`,`Number`)
```

This CONCAT is stored in a column as `ID`. I then need to be able to SELECT `ID` by number

1. ZYX00001
2. ABC00002
3. PQR00003
4. HIJ00004

Not

1. ABC00002
2. HIJ00004
3. PQR00003
4. ZYX00001

I have created a `mergedID` column within the `tempid` table and use the following code to overcome my problem

```
UPDATE `tempid` SET `mergedID` = CONCAT(`Letter`,`Number`); INSERT INTO `main` (`ID`) VALUES (`mergedID`)
```

This gives me the correct ID now with the zeros included, but I feel there is a better way to do this.

I can now carry out the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `main` ORDER BY RIGHT(`ID`,5)
```

I believe I have carried out research to achieve this solution and don't warrant a negative rating.

Comment: what data types are the columns?

Comment: You appear to be attempting to store derived data. This is sometimes frowned upon.

Comment: Yes it is a zero filled column

Comment: I don't see how concat removes the leading zeroes; [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f54b/4).

Comment: It seems to remove them when I place the CONCAT into another table

Comment: I have now included a new column in the `tempid` table and got the result I require, however I am unable to sort by number.

Comment: @Strawberry I am keeping track of the last id number in a separate table, adding a 3letter code to it and using the result in my main table.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do this:

`CONCAT(Letters, CAST(Number AS varchar))`

Cast your INT as a VARCHAR so the datatypes match

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was doing:

(in php):

```
$week_day =  date('d', $week_start);
```

In SQL

```
SELECT (... other stuff), CONCAT( MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) + 10, {$week_day},  LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 99999.99), 5, '0') ) AS CurrInvoice
```

I used this same method to create this 9-character field for about 12 years, thru various versions of MySql and MariaDb (and various servers) with no problem at all -- without CAST or quote marks for the '$week_day' field. **UNTIL November of 2020**. After that, either my host changed a config or MariaDb changed something because everytime the '$week_day' value was less than 10, the CONCAT chopped off the leading zero that was produced by the PHP command (date('d', blahblah) ) and created an **8-character field**. I only recently noticed this, so I simply quoted the $week_day variable in the SQL (e.g., I used **'**{$week_day}**'**), with the result that the CONCAT correctly maintained the leading zero if the day was less than 10. This is an old thread so apparently some people always had to CAST a number with a leading zero in order to keep it, but I'm telling you that I never had to do that until recently. My MariaDb version is 10.2.37-MariaDB and I know that's pretty old but the version did NOT change in November -- something did though.
Anyway, yeah, I should have always CAST that numeric part -- live and learn.

Answer (score -1):

**Hey....you use Number datatype is INT so remove all 0 before int value
See... 00005 Database table Add only 5.**

```
Answer:-

1.) Datatype change

OR

2.) Your query add static four Zero 
    See..
    SELECT CONCAT(Letters,'0000',Number) from <Table Name>
```